# The function tries to reference a deleted function, but the function is set to delete already

Tags: c++, function, reference

I am trying to check if all of my functions in the errormessage class are working in the main function, but the problem is that **I get an error message at "T" and "e" located beside cout <<** in the Main.cpp

Saying I am trying to reference a deleted function sict::ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const sict::ErrorMessage&).

However, I already set this function to delete in the header. Any idea as to why this error occurs?

**Header file**

```
#ifndef SICT_ERROR_H_
#define SICT_ERROR_H_
namespace sict {
    class ErrorMessage {
        char* m_message;
    public:

        ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage = nullptr);
        ErrorMessage(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete;
        ErrorMessage& operator=(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete;
        virtual ~ErrorMessage();
        void clear();
        bool isClear() const;
        void message(const char* str);
        const char* message() const;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, ErrorMessage);
}
#endif
```

**Cpp file**

```
#include "ErrorMessage.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace sict {

    ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage) {
        m_message = nullptr;
        message(errorMessage);
    }
    void ErrorMessage::clear() {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = nullptr;
    }
    void ErrorMessage::message(const char* str) {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(m_message, str);
    }
    const char* ErrorMessage::message() const {
        return m_message;
    }
    ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage() {
        clear();
    }
    bool ErrorMessage::isClear() const {
        if (m_message == nullptr) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, ErrorMessage error) {
        if (!(error.isClear())) {
            ostr << error.message();
        }
        return ostr;
    }


}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorMessage.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

int main() {
    ErrorMessage T("Testing Error Message Module");
    ErrorMessage e;
    int ret = 0;
    bool ok = true;
    cout << T << endl << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
    if (!e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "===========| Long Message\r";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            cout << "*";
            cout.flush();
        }
        e.message("Some error message that is really long long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long");
    }
    cout << '*' << endl;
    cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
    if (e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;

    e.message("Short Message");
    cout << e << endl << e.message() << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
    if (e.isClear()) ok = false;

    e.clear();
    cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
    if (!e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;

    if (ok) {
        cout << "You passed all the tests!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You did not pass all the tests" << endl;
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is what `= delete` is supposed to do.  What were you trying to use it for?  Did you maybe want `= default`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, ErrorMessage error)
```

Your `<<` is accepting an `ErrorMessage` by value so it must copy `T` and `e` in order to be passed to the function (and therefore attempting to use the deleted copy constructor)

Try passing by const reference:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const ErrorMessage& error)
```

Comment: now it puts me to break saying exception thrown at 0x0F5B1FD0 arrow indicating m_message = new char[strlen(str)+1]; located at void errorMessage(const char* str) in .cpp

Comment: what is `str` going to be when you initialize `e`? That may or may not solve your new issue but this should really be posted as a separate question since your original problem was solved)